# Which data format for efficient socket communication in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, sockets, interprocess

I want to implement a profiler which tracks the state of the JVM in real time. I am not sure which data format would be appropriate for this task as I have to receive updates of the state of the JVM.

I thought XML would be great, but with every change sending the whole XML data seems to be very bogus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe JSON Format?  http://www.json.org/

Comment: I really like JSON, I believe its alot superior to XML. However this does not answer my question, as I believe it would be cumbersome to transmit always the whole VM state in form of JSON/XML instead of just push the changes.

Comment: @platzhirsch, you can't escape that no matter the transport, you either implement parsing of individual state characteristics and send only those or parse the entire state of the machine in one go, resulting in you having to send the entire state.

Comment: It is an answer and  togehter with Shinnok you get a complete "idea". At first how would you like to extract the measurements, and of course what  you want to measure. Than you can think on how to send it elswhere and for that JSON is "one" way. If you like you can send a fixed size buffer also. But you have to extract the information and package them.